# Power BI License required

Tags: powerbi

I have Power BI Pro and have created some reports. Can i know what license do the users need to have in order to have access to the report content once it is shared with them?  They are currently using the Pro Trial which will expire in 2 months or so. Do all the users need to have the pro license to view the report.  Can anyone please let me know more about it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when sharing both the creator and the viewer needs Pro licenses (see [Share Power BI dashboards and reports with coworkers and others](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-share-dashboards)), unless the workspace has Premium capacity assigned to it (see [Unlimited content sharing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-premium-what-is#unlimited-content-sharing)):

> With sharing, whether you share content inside or outside your organization, you need a Power BI Pro license. Your recipients also need [Power BI Pro licenses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/fundamentals/service-features-license-type), unless the content is in a [Premium capacity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-premium-what-is).

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrey for your quick reply.